# The antonym of 'simplicity' is not exactly what I'm looking for

Tags: word-request, antonyms

Today is the birthday of [Mahatma Gandhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi) a man known for his [simplicity](http://www.motivationalmemo.com/mahatma-gandhis-simplicity-faith/). He refrained from any luxury or comfort. He was a true leader and exactly opposite to today's politicians and so called leaders. I am in search of an antonym to describe these false leaders.

> Mahatma was known for his simplicity, today's politicians are known for ____________?

I tried [finding the antonym](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/simplicity) but ended up with words like *difficulties, complexities...* and so on. You know that's not what I'm looking for. I mean *simplicity* in living, whereas the thesaurus considers *a simple thing* to to be in opposition to *a complex thing*.

Comment: I think you are looking for something on the lines of- **Lavishness(noun), Lavish(adj), Opulent(adj), or Profligate(adj)**. Some more similar words: [here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lavish) and [here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lavish).

Comment: Yes, Lavishness is close!

Comment: How about *extravagance*?

Comment: "He refrained <del>himself</del> from luxury or comfort."

Comment: I think looking at the opposite of [ascetic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ascetic?s=ts) might help. That reference lists self-indulgent as an antonym, although there might be better words out there.

Comment: Deciding on an antonym isn't always necessary. "*Unlike* today's politicians, Mahatma Gandhi was known for his simplicity." Using 'unlike' implies the *exact* opposite. -Wouldn't Gandhi find it unkosher to use stereotypes anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe one of these would do?

- Extravagant
- Baroque
- Wasteful
- Rich
- Lavish
- Opulent
- Luxurious
- Decadent

Comment: Decadent was the first word I thought of as opposite to Mahatma Gandhi :)

Comment: Yes, decadence would fit. I think it is the best choice.

Comment: "Baroque" means intricate and complex, the meaning the poster said he was not looking for. "Wasteful" is debatable: one could live in luxury without being wasteful if everything spent did indeed contribute to your greater comfort, and one could certainly be wasteful without living in luxury. The others all give the intended idea, I believe. Not that the second to last should be spelled "luxurious". Also, these convey different degrees. "Decadent" is the most extreme of the list, I think too extreme for this context. I'd add more mild words or phrases, like "comfort-seeking".

Comment: "Decadence" is also the first one I thought of, along with "Excess".

Comment: Excessive is nice too.
Baroque can be used in the meaning "too complex for the purpose" and therefore qualifies in my mind.
Wasteful is clearly not opposite to simple, but might still  be the opposite of Ghandi.
I find that "comfort-seeking" is not in the same league as the others, and that decadent is exactly the opposite of Ghandi.

Comment: Yes, looked upon that. *Decadence* is better among all. Also, *lavish* and *extravagant* are good words. Overall, nice and acceptable answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Today's politicians are known for their bureaucracy.

> [Bureaucracies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bureaucracy) are criticized when they become too complex

Comment: "Bueaucracy" could be the opposite of "simplicity" in politics, but I don't think that's the meaning the poster is looking for. I believe he's talking about comfort or luxury.